# Create 3 color conditional formatting with axlsx

Tags: ruby, axlsx

With axlsx, the following

```
color_scale = Axlsx::ColorScale.new do |c_s|
  c_s.colors[1].rgb = "FFFFFF00"
end
color_scale.add :type => :percentile, :val => 50, :color => "FF00FF00"
worksheet.add_conditional_formatting("B3:B100", { :type => :colorScale, :operator => :greaterThan, :formula => "100000", :priority => 1, :color_scale => color_scale })
```

creates a basic 3 color conditional formatting, but the colors are pretty garish, making it hard to distinguish between slightly smaller and slightly larger values.

Is it necessary to reverse-engineer the colors Excel uses in order to create something that looks like the default 3 color conditional formatting that Excel provides?

Comment: Can't you just put your ideal Excel page and a color picker side by side, and adjust the colors you want on the color picker?

Comment: I think we can do better than that.

Answer (score 5):

For color scales, Excel will by default prefer Themes, while Axlsx is currently expecting you to specify exactly what you want. This is partly for interoperability but mostly because I have not ran into a use case that requires similarity to Excel's defaults.

That said, Axlsx should do what it can to give you some sensible defaults and I am sure you can understand how your request is an excellent opportunity to improve this area.

Would you be so kind as to send me a sample xlsx of what you are trying to achieve?
I am sure that I can add a bit of sugar in to make you a bit happier with the results you are seeing now and hopefully benefit the other users of the gem.

**UPDATE 2012.11.16**

Axlsx has been updated to version 1.3.4 to provide two class methods on ColorScale to create new ColorScale objects with sensible defaults for two-tone and three-tone color scaling.

Examples:

```
# to make a three tone color scale
color_scale = Axlsx::ColorScale.three_tone

# to make a two tone color scale
color_scale = Axlsx::ColorScale.two_tone

# To make a customized color scale you, pass hashes consisting of 
# type, val and color key-value pairs as arguments to the initializer.
# This example that creates the same three tone color scale as 
# Axlsx::ColorScale.three_tone
color_scale = Axlsx::ColorScale.new({:type => :min, :val => 0, :color => 'FFF8696B'},
                 {:type => :percent, :val => '50', :color => 'FFFFEB84'},
                 {:type => :max, :val => 0, :color => 'FF63BE7B'})
```